# MVC: MultiSelectList Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to bind a ListBox in my partial view but I'm getting the exception...

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Referencing `@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedRoles, Model.Roles)`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Model:

```
public class RegisterModel {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string[] SelectedRoles { get; set; }
    public MultiSelectList Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller  {
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult _AddUser() {
        var model = new RegisterModel {
            Roles = new MultiSelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles())
        };

        return View(model);
    }

}
```

PartialView _AddUser.cshtml:

```
@model RobotDog.Models.RegisterModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("_AddUser","Admin", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "input-xlarge", @placeholder = "Email"})
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserName, new { @class = "input-xlarge", @placeholder = "User Name"})
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "input-xlarge", @placeholder = "Password"})
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedRoles, Model.Roles)
}
```

Here is the view that is referencing _AddUser.cshtml
Users.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<RobotDog.Models.UserModel>
<table></table>
<div id="addUser">
    @Html.Partial("_AddUser", new ViewDataDictionary())
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your example is that by calling @Html.Partial you're rendering the partial _AddUser without ever going through the controller _AddUser method. This means that the Model of the partial view has no Model.Roles to access. You can resolve this a couple of different ways.

One possibility is to use @Html.RenderAction or @Html.Action to call the controller method and let the controller method _AddUser populate the values as you've set it up to do.

Comment: One question, this seems to be rending the partial wrapped inside the layout. In other words, the partialView is wrapped in `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: @bflemi3 - You're getting a rendered view with another html, head, and body inside of the main view? Are you using Html.Action or Html.RenderAction?

Comment: When would I use RenderAction? I'm confused by these two.

Comment: @bflemi3 - I don't know of any particularly strong views on this to be honest. As the name implies, RenderAction renders the output directly to the stream rather than returning a string to be included in the ultimately rendered view. Haack suggests that it's a better choice when rendering a large amount of data and I wouldn't disagree but I haven't personally run into a situation where this distinction made a material difference.